# Android statusbar notification

Tags: java, android

How to get full content of notification in Lolipop or above devices.
I am unable to get notification detail like buttons and icons in notification with this.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker ="";
    if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
        ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    }

    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    Log.i("Package",pack);
    Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
    Log.i("Title",title);
    Log.i("Text",text);

    Intent msgs = new Intent("Msg");
    msgs.putExtra("package", pack);
    msgs.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
    msgs.putExtra("title", title);
    msgs.putExtra("text", text);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen you did not create your notification. You need a notification builder just after your notification is received in your application.

Hence in the receiver of your broadcast, you need to create the notification to be shown in your status bar like the following.

```
// Inside your broadcast receiver 
int notificationID = new Random().nextInt();
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourHomeActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "BUTTON 1", myIntentToButtonOneScreen)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "BUTTON 2", myIntentToButtonTwoScreen)  // #1
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "BUTTON 3", myIntentToButtonThreeScreen) 
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

if (result != null)
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(result);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

This is just a sample code which might not work. But this is just to give you an idea. Please follow [this developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for better understanding.

**Update**

Based on the comment asking for the notification listener service, here's sample code on how you can listen to notification that was sent to your mobile. Considering you have used Firebase cloud messaging.

```
public class FCMListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private FCMNotificationResponse mFcmNotificationResponse;
    private RemoteMessage.Notification notification;

    private Map data;
    private String from;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        parseRemoteMessage(message);
    }

    private void parseRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
        from = message.getFrom();
        data = message.getData();
        notification = message.getNotification();

        Logger.logD("Message", "From: " + from);

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (data.size() > 0) {
            Logger.logD("Data", "Message data payload: " + data.toString());
            setNotificationResponseFromData(data);
        }

        createNotification(this, notification.getTitle(), notification.getBody(), mFcmNotificationResponse.getIcon());
    }

    // Here you parse the JSON body received from notification
    private void setNotificationResponseFromData(Map data) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(data);
        mFcmNotificationResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, FCMNotificationResponse.class);
    }

    private void createNotification(Context context, String title, String message, String imageUrl) {
        new CreateNotificationAsyncTask(context, title,
                message, imageUrl).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

`onMessageReceived` function is called when a notification is received. Then you need to parse your data and then create the notification accordingly.

Comment: i do not want create notification instead i want recieve active notifications in statusbar.

Comment: What do you mean by receiving notification? I think you have a push server already from where you are sending those notification right? Then you need to register to that server when your application launches and get a push registration id to make your application enabled for receiving the notification from GCM or FCM.

Comment: notification listener to recieve active notifications in statusbar

Comment: Please check the updated answer and upvote and then accept the answer if you find it helpful. Thanks.